# content disposition header on nginx

Tags: php, mysql, content-disposition

I'm running a file hosting site on nginx where files are stored on the server with random file names.

When a user wants to download the file, I'd like to fetch the original name from a MySQL database and download it with that name using `content-disposition`.

I also want this to work with direct links to the file but have no idea how to set `content-disposition` this way. I've seen other sites do this, but I'm not sure how to build it myself.

Comment: Formatting and clarity

Comment: Oops, that was supposed to say "Edited for formatting and clarity." haha